# On FOLLOW-Sets of Grammars

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, generator, ll-grammar

Here http://slkpg.byethost7.com/llkparse.html the FOLLOW_k-Sets are defined

"The FOLLOWk set of a string of
   symbols in a grammar is a set of k-length terminal symbol strings in 
   the grammar that may follow the string of symbols in some 
   sentential form derivable in the grammar"

First i have a quation regarding the example under the link, there for Grammar 4.2

```
     A  -->  a <Baa> a a              
     A  -->  b <Bba> b a
 <Baa>  -->  b
 <Baa>  -->
 <Bba>  -->  b
 <Bba>  -->
```

It is said that:

```
FIRST2 ( A ) = { aa, ab, bb }
FIRST2 ( <Baa> ) = { epsilon }
FIRST2 ( <Bba> ) = { epsilon }

FOLLOW2 ( <Baa> ) = { aa }
FOLLOW2 ( <Bba> ) = { ba }
```

But i am asking myself why not

```
FIRST2 ( <Baa> ) = { epsilon, b }
FIRST2 ( <Bba> ) = { epsilon, b }
```

because from for example  also a single b could be derived.

Furthermore for the grammar

```
S -> X 
X -> aX
X -> aY
Y -> epsilon
```

i am unsure of the set

```
FOLLOW2(S)
```

is it empty, { epsilon } , or { a, aa } because these string are derivable, or is it just important what comes after S, and because S is the startsymbol nothing comes behind it, but then should i write FOLLOW2(S) = \empyset or FOLLOW2(S) = { epsilon }?

Answer (score 0):

FOLLOWk(S) is empty for any k, because nothing can follow S at all. I don't know what you mean by 'because these strings are derivable', but as they cannot follow S it's irrelevant anyway.

Comment: "derivable" I think he means one can get strings like `aa` or `a` from `epsilon`. (supposedly because of production rules that allows this), as in this [pronouncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_semantics_of_grammars)